# n-"Kings" Problem

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I was thinking on some variations of the n-Queen problem until I reached the following problem I couldn't solve:
How many ways are there to put $n$ kings (as in a chess game) on a $n\times n$ chessboard such that no two kings threaten each other?
I'm not so optimistic that it would be solved in "non purely computational" methods. I've tried recursions, bijection and almost anything in my own knowledge yet I have achieved nothing.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A002464 (though there's an additional constraint there, that there be just one king in each row and column).

Comment: @BarryCipra I think that's slightly different.

Comment: This question does not require that each King be on a different row or column.

Comment: @Barry Cipra I've seen this sequence before. Actually that was one of my motivations to think of this problem yet with having the additional constraint, having a recursive algorithm would be possible which is not useful here.

Comment: Yet now that I see A279112,A279113,A279114,A279115 I don't think there is a general answer to this problem.

Comment: Problems of this kind will typically specify whether symmetries are to be counted as distinct solutions, e.g. rotations and reflections of the board.  In any case outlining the few small cases that can be counted "by inspection" would help Readers understand how you wish them to be counted.

Comment: @Trebor, yes, you may have seen my comment before I edited in the parenthetical disclaimer. I have a vague recollection of having seen the OP's version of the non-attacking kings problem before, but I can't quite put my finger on it (and may be misremembering).

Comment: Ah, what I was trying to remember is http://www.math.clemson.edu/~kevja/REU/2005/Kings2.pdf -- but that's still different from what the OP wants to count. But it may have some useful ideas.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A201513 is this specific sequence (at least according to the Kotěšovec book), BTW.

Comment: The Kotesovec book alluded to in Aryan's answer refers to https://oeis.org/A201513 which is the sequence the OP wants (but there's not much there except a reference to the Kotesovec book!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the section 2.1.2 book "Non-attacking chess pieces" by "Václav Kotěšovec", the general answer does exist and is equal to the following :
$$
\frac{n^{2n}}{n!}\left(1-\frac{9(n-1)n}{2n^2}+\frac{(n-1)n(243n^2-439n-142)}{24n^4}-\ldots\right)
$$
[image]

Comment: ...that seems more like an asymptotic estimate than a 'general answer', especially with an apparently infinite series with no general formula for its terms.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, the series might tacitly terminate if there's a build-up of factors $(n-k)$ in the numerator, culminating in an $n-n$.

Comment: @BarryCipra True enough. Without a formula for those messy polynomials I can't imagine proving integrality of the resulting expression, though. Taking $n$ to be some medium-largish prime does not seem likely to yield fruitful results in the numerator.

Comment: The discriminant on the quadratic in the third term, for instance, is 330745 = 5 * 29 * 2281; with none of the numbers themselves or that discriminant having particularly nice forms it's _really_ hard to see where those coefficients are coming from.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki It's not an asymptomatic estimate! Yet it also presents one in the rest of the topic. The pattern is that it takes product of $i$ consequent terms, times an additional polynomial. The additional polynomials in the presented terms are (respectively) : $$9n-9,243n^2-439n-142,\dotsb$$ For more information about these additional polynomials check the topic in the book

Comment: The book was in Russian and I had a hard time translating it but before presenting this formula it clearly referenced to another page of the book for "how to get the series"

Comment: I found the book online at http://www.kotesovec.cz/books/kotesovec_non_attacking_chess_pieces_2013_6ed.pdf

Comment: It is a really fun book, it has calculated nearly all "non-attacking" chess problems. The author is a mathematician "and" a professional chess player which explains the whole motivation of such a book XD